# Any module similar to Redirection in wordpress for Prestashop

Tags: wordpress, prestashop, redirect, prestashop-1.6

I recently came across [Redirection plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) for wordpress which makes it very easy to capture links which are creating 404 errors and then set 301 redirections for the same. I am looking for something similar for my prestashop site too. Is there any module for prestashop? If not, is there some other way for me to modify the code to track 404 pages or through the apache access/error logs.

Comment: Prestashop has its own 404 page

Comment: Yes, I would like to track what was the original URL which caused 404 page so that I can fix it if it is a broken URL or just set 301 redirections as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In /override/controllers/front/
create a file called: PageNotFoundController.php

we enter:

```
class PageNotFoundController extends PageNotFoundControllerCore
    {

    public function initContent()
    {
        $url ="new path to redirect";
        header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
        header('Location: '.$url;
        ob_end_flush();
        exit;
     }
}
```

delete cache/class_index.php